# How to Post Parameter in Xamarin?

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have a simple syntax for send my parameter. How to send parameter in `POST` method?

```
String email = _emailText.Text.ToString();
String password = _passwordText.Text.ToString();

//login
string _url = String.Format ("http://192.168.88.161:99/Login/AjaxLogin?username={0}&password{1}", email, password);

// Declare HTTP Client and get JSON data from defined URL above
System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
string content = await client.GetStringAsync(_url);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you build your code, you are sending a `GET` request. So instead of `client.GetStringAsync(_url);` use

```
var url = "http://192.168.88.161:99/Login/AjaxLogin";
var content = new StringContent(String.Format("username={0}&password{1}", email, password), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```